# Should incorrect information be allowed? what is the purpose?

Tags: discussion

There are 2 points to this.

What is the factual point of Stack Overflow? I asked something yesterday about Stack Overflow being fit for purpose with user moderators, and this sparked a whole other debate. So I removed it. But as a follow up from it: What is Stack Overflow?

Someone yesterday said it was supposed to be like Wikipedia, for users-asked question about programming. Well if this is the case, incorrect or obsolete information should be removed. Wikipedia polices its system for incorrect information frequently, and corrects it very fast.

Is it just supposed to be a Q&A for providing support to users, whether the information is correct or incorrect? If this is the case, why are we losing rep for down voting answers that are incorrect? Also against this point: why are there badges for keeping information correct, for example [the peer pressure badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/38/peer-pressure)?

What is Stack Overflow supposed to do? Is it supposed to provide factual answers like Wikipedia or is it just a Q&A, and if so why are users punished for down voting an incorrect answer? Or do you think its supposed to be something else?

And following that, is it doing what you think it should be doing? As another note, why are user moderators just voting with the highest scored users as I mentioned yesterday? I would much prefer incorrect information was removed, and yes that includes my own. For a developer time is everything and an answer that is incorrect will just waste developers time.

This is a discussion, not an argument, not a dig, just a discussion. What is Stack Overflow supposed to do now and is it doing it?

Comment: "As another note, why are user moderators just voting with the highest scored users as I mentioned yesterday?" - I don't see what that has to do with the rest of your post, and that lacks supporting evidence. (Also, please, shorter sentences. Your post was very hard to read.)

Comment: Sorry I'm dyslexic, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27548217/cant-insert-data-in-mysql-database/27548547#27548547 is the evidence however this got changed yeterday but look at the comments and the user moderators support information saying that what the OP was doing was not possible when I proved it was possible you can mix `mysql_real_escape_string` with `mysqli_query` i stated it was not recommended but it is possible this is what sparked the debate about what SO is supposed to be when i got told it was like `Wikipedia`

Comment: There's no moderators there, just users (with a **lot** of PHP experience). I don't get your point though. Not everything that "can be done", or "appears to work", should be done. Bad advice isn't welcome.

Comment: `user moderators` Not moderators with the diamond thing i am not saying it is but if "Bad advice isn't welcome" why is incorrect information welcome then? and i did state it was not recommended i was just trying to prove that what he said of it can not be done was incorrect

Comment: Your answer doesn't state the requirements for it to work, and doesn't state that it is not recommended. As it stands, it is incorrect and the comments you got are correct. If you amend your answer to state the requirements, and add a big, fat warning that it's a stupid thing to do, then you'd be good - but why would you want to do that?

Comment: My answer was using the OP's code that was not part of the problem he was having that why i did not state it other users were stating it as the fact that it was not working when this was incorrect i left it out of my answer for the very reason of it was not part of the solution to the problem he was having. however the comments we're starting it was incorrect as they stated you could not mix the API's when you can. this is why it was in the comments and i did state a few times it's not recommended

Comment: Thank you for not ranting (as much) this time. Having read the linked question, I don't see "user moderators" (which are really just normal users) voting with the "highest scored (rep?) users. In fact, the other two answers are from *lower* rep users and received more votes than yours. Unless of course, you are referring to the *comment* votes, which don't matter anyways (they just indicate agreement, can you really argue with that?)

Comment: To voters: Note that this is a *discussion* not a *feature-request*. Votes should not indicate agreement/disagreement with the content of the post, but the post's quality

Comment: Relevant: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15863/why-do-you-lose-reputation-for-down-voting and: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62130/if-downvoting-is-so-important-why-does-it-cost-reputation

Comment: I'm at a loss now with -6 on the Question and 2 votes to close why? what is inappropriate about this question? i asked a question that there are some really good answers to only 3 people have commented on this question. This goes back to the users should be forced to comment to down vote other wise you got down voted for the fact they don't like what your asking not if its a fit question for the site your on!

Answer (score 5):

Stack Overflow is a commercial business founded on the desire of some people to get help and the willingness of other people to provide help. As a business, it depends on many people using the site. To the great credit of its owners, they strive to get this traffic by looking for ways to make the site useful, not just by clickbait.

The only way to scale this is to recruit all of us, the unwashed masses, into a crowdsource. Crowdsourcing has benefits and limitations. Sometimes the crowd does dumb things, or doesn't do smart things as fast as you might like. To get it to work at all, decisions have to be distributed across the crowd so that no single person has too much influence over too little space and time. Charging for downvotes is part of the rate limiting mechanism, and it also tends to recruit more downvotes from those people who have earned more upvotes.

Comment: but as you have stated there the higher rep the more power. However the more power the more rep and it gets to a point that new members with low rep are losing out to higher rep users causing a power struggle effect as with the question in my comments i was arguing with a High Rep who just got more rep for arguing even though the point he was arguing was incorrect he still got up votes on comments this causes a  "we're higher than you we know more than you." of late back when i first started using SO this was not the case people cared about the quality of information provided

Comment: Trivially more power. The ability to cast more downvotes with less feeling of losing something.

Comment: but it's more than down votes, as that very rep gives them more power with the `user moderation` privileges why would a user ever want to lose that power so users will work with each other to prevent them dropping below the mark.

Comment: It's a crowd. There are thousands of people. 'Work together'? Only in a hollywood paranoid film.

Comment: you never heard of Mob Mentality it's far worse on the internet as people act more excuse the term `dickish` on the internet than they would in real life look at some of the stories of Social Media Bulling on the internet the number of people involved is a lot more than would be if it we're playground bullying

Comment: however the proof is there you made a quip trying to discredit my valid cross examination talking about the power struggle effect and it got upvoted!

Comment: @MartinBarker You get no reputation for comment votes, they just get more visibility. There was no "power struggle", you had a disagreement with another user, other users thought he was right and you weren't. You don't even have any downvotes on the answer!

Answer (score 4):

To answer the titular question: Should incorrect information be allowed? **No! ..and yes**.

Obviously we don't want incorrect information being perpetuated through the site. However, no one person, *especially* a (diamond) moderator or random reviewer, can be guaranteed to have enough domain knowledge to make a correct/incorrect determination. Thats why flags for "incorrectness" are always declined.

We give users *with* the domain knowledge an opportunity to correct the problem by *downvoting* and *commenting*. Downvoting moves the content towards the bottom of the page, puts a big negative number next to the post, and (eventually) dims the content out so its obvious that the community doesn't agree with the content. Additionally, 20K users can vote to delete answers that are negatively scored.

Comments inform you (and future visitors) that other users feel the answer has problems (among other things). Upvoting comments does nothing but indicate agreement, and simply raises the visibility of the comment (no reputation is earned).

Moving quickly through the body questions:

- Stack Overflow is **not** wikipedia. Its not a bunch of articles. We certainly have the community curation of content concept from there though.
- Yes, we are a Q&A site, though not for supporting users. We are trying to build a knowledge base of questions and answers to programming problems. In addition, we want this information to be useful for future visitors.
- You lose reputation for downvoting *answers* to avoid abuse, and to make sure that you feel strongly enough that the post isn't useful. You used to lose rep for downvoting *questions* but due to the flood of crap, they removed that restriction in order for us to moderate those posts more effectively.
- My personal belief is that Stack Overflow is doing what it should be doing. Could it be doing it more effectively? Sure, but the current system works pretty well.
- Finally, I have never noticed users agreeing (*especially in comments*) with another user just because they are high rep. I can't say with certainty that it never happens, but I don't think its a plague. If you have a suggestion on how to curtail that further, feel free to post it.

Comment: to your first point, there is no flag for incorrect answers though you would not believe the number of times i have searched for a problem found a SO Question that is Answered but the answer is incorrect or does not work / compile in C++. now i understand some posts it's just impossible for some one to know if it will work or not but most of the time there will be a moderator that knows the language as they got the rep from some where to apply to be a moderator.

Comment: @MartinBarker You are of course, welcome to downvote such answers when you find them, or suggest an edit (please consider leaving a comment of course). However, you cannot remotely guarantee that *any* diamond moderator will know the language, let alone the one handling the flag! We have 17 moderators as of this posting. There are *far* more tags/languages/technologies.

Answer (score 3):

Stack Overflow is a Q&A website, but not for *just* helping *single* users. All questions and answers given here should be helpful for other users as well, when they have the same or similar problems. However this does not mean answers are not factual. All answers provided should be helpful to the person who asked the question, in some way. If an answer is incorrect it should be downvoted or edited to answer the question.

You lose reputation for downvoting an answer because it is instead recommend to edit the answer so it answers the question. If you think an answer is absolute nonsens and shouldn't be posted in the first place, you can flag this answer. If you think an answer is bad, you can downvote it, but because of the results of this (the person who answered the question losing reputation) there is a small *punishment* which will cause you to lose some reputation. Think of it as some form of fraud-protection.

Comment: So this follows with why do we lose rep for telling a user there answer is incorrect, and should answers / comments that are just wrong be flagged for removal when there is evidence proving the answer or comment to be incorrect? and i don't mean just incorrrect to the question this could be just a missunderstanding to the question i mean stating facts that are incorrect

Comment: You do not lose reputation for telling someones answer is incorrect: You lose reputation when your answer/question/.. gets downvoted by another user. This has the same result, however the approach is quite different, as this means another user found your post not helpful, or downvoted it for another reason. You cannot downvote comments, so as far as I know you also don't lose reputation for commenting on someones question or answer.

Comment: if you down vote a answer you lose 2 reputation for doing so. Sorry i updated and not with comments just about the flagging for them :)

Comment: Ah, edited my answer :-)

Comment: @MartinBarker it's -1 for downvoting an answer, not -2. And why should be pretty obvious - if downvotes on answers were free, answerers could just downvote all other answers in order to get OP to accept theirs.

Comment: Ok so would it not be better that when a user has answered a question they can only down vote answers on the same question after they have commented on the answer there wanting to down vote this then forces them to explain a down vote?